# Basement floor drain, sloped floor toward the drain. how do you install and preserve the slope for either porcelain or vinyl tiles?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring, porcelain

I am being told that both have challenges as following:

**-porcelain tiles** (in particular large ones -20"x20" is what I had in mind) will be difficult to slope without ending up with vertically misaligned pieces. You will need to use self leveling cement which could be expensive and it defeats the purpose of having a drain there

**-vinyl tiles** are more flexible but then since the slope is there there is an issue with making them follow the slope as the snap in edges require the tiles to be mostly aligned in order to hold them together (my understanding) This is a floating floor, not glued to the underneath concrete excepting the edges near the walls

So vinyl would probably be easier to implement but then how do you keep the vinyl planks from floating and creating a gap between the concrete slab and themselves

Update

Here is the layout:
1-bathroom
2-laudry room
3 hallway/storage area
4 hallway
5 kitchen with the drain (small circle on the rendering)
6 hallway
-I am tiling everything you see in the picture as tiled(square tiles)
-the drain seem to be there for flooding
-the north south dividing wall is cinder blocks and I am sure the builder did not design the laundry room to drain to the kitchen
-there might be a drain in the #2 (laundry) but I doubt, there is no slope there
-the drain goes to the main drain of the house that drains the plumbing for 1 and 5 and their main floor counter parts just above 1 and 5.
-the 4 area has a little bit of slope bin front of that door between 4 and 5 but 3 and 2 are pretty much flat and so is 6. The slope is centered in 5  and it sinks like bowl I think the lowest point is 3/4"

[image]
Update2:
Can this be done with two concentric rows of toles around the drain?
[image]

Comment: Imagine it is not a single flat slope, but a few slopes that meet at the drain.  Imagine also where the slopes change is not hard straight line.  This would make it hard to use large squares or long pieces of rigid flooring.

Comment: that could be dealt with by creating 4 sloped plans converging toward the drain. You create those by adding more thin set mortar which can be thinker for LHTs

Comment: Smaller porcelain tiles can be sloped more easily than the large ones. You could have a decorative apron of smaller tiles around the drain where the slope may be the least gradual.

Comment: I considered that too but the slopes are kind of longer and that will ruin the look. I also considered hexagonal tiles

Comment: A description of the slopes might give someone an idea.  Many different types of slopes to a floor drain.  Does it just kind of sink down like a bowl, or four flat slopes from each wall to a centre?

Comment: Does the drain discharge to a septic system/waste pipe? What scenarios are you contemplating for the drain? Washing the floor down?

Comment: Line up some tiles directly on the floor (without thin-set) starting at the drain using the grout joint width you are contemplating and examine the joints closely to see if there's an abrupt and marked change of slope at any point. Repeat this exercise at various locations around the drain, north, east, south, west, and in-between.

Comment: If enough ceiling height(>8ft), could add a sub floor and get rid of dealing with slopes.  Imagine you are not going to use the drain for a shower.

Comment: details added
@crip659: how does the subflor deal with the slope. If it is some membrane or wood planks I do not see how this will help

Comment: Did not say it would be easy, but you raise the floor up a bit so you have a flat floor to lay non-bendable flooring.  Bottom of the joists/risers would match the floors curve/slope, but the tops would be flat.  At the wall a 1 and 1/2 inch deep piece of wood you start cutting at 3/4 inch, so at the deep(drain) part the wood be 1 1/2.  Would raise the floor about an inch and a half to two inches.  Risers plus sub floor panels.

Comment: No wayThat air gap calls for mold  and humidity

Comment: Added a possible solution ..see the update2...would this work?